# Setting up Netflix Hystrix to use the metrics dashboard

Tags: java, netflix

I'm using Netflix's [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki) library on a project to provide fault tolerance, so that I can keep a track of the current load on services, see any failed services and avoid points of failure before they occur.

So far, I have set up a basic example of Hystrix in Eclipse, where I've created a dynamic web application, created a Tomcat server and am able to successfully resort to the fallBack methods that Hystrix provides in its HystrixCommand object when a request to a service times out, fails etc.

The next thing I'd like to do is to implement the actual metrics dashboard, where [I've been following the instructions here](http://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard). Here I have two problems:

- I don't know whether I need to fire up metrics for each of the HystrixCommands manually, or whether this is automated.
- I have downloaded the hystrix-metrics-event-stream-1.3.3.jar in order to expose the metrics to the dashboard, but when I go to the address localhost:8080/HystrixServer/hystrix.stream, I receive a NullPointerException pointing to HystrixMetricsPoller, which is inside of the downloaded jar file.

There isn't that much documentation around, and I haven't found anything for implementing the metrics and dashboard side of things, so feel completely in the dark about this right now.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Thanks,
Karl.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report potentially related to this at https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/180

As for the documentation, have you looked at https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard#installation-of-dashboard ?